# Image moves up after being resized by resizing-script

Tags: jquery, css, image, window, image-resizing

I've an image

```
<img onclick="$('#daltonempire').popover('toggle');" id="theimg" alt="Dalton Empire" class="sticktofooter" src="img/DE%20Logo.png" width="529" height="544"/>
```

and the corresponding `sticktofooter` class's css is

```
.sticktofooter {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    right:1%;
    z-index:99;
}
```

And the purpose is that the image is fixed to the bottom of the window, and (fortunately,) it works!

The problem however, is my resizing script...
I've this function:

```
function doimgheight(){
        thegoodheight = Math.round($(window).height() / 4);
        thescale = thegoodheight / 544  ;
        $('#theimg').css({
            "-webkit-transform": "scale(" + thescale + ")",
            "-moz-transform": "scale(" + thescale + ")",
            "-o-transform": "scale(" + thescale + ")",
            "transform": "scale(" + thescale + ")"
        });
}
```

Which is called during `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).resize()`.
The purpose is to, at page load, make the image (544px) 1/4th of the window size.
Also at `$(window).resize()`, it'll make the image 1/4th of the resized/resizing window's size.

The script also works fine, it smoothly resizes the image to 1/4th of the window's size.

**The problem is,** that the css class only works when I disable the `doimgheight()` function (simply by commenting it). When the script and css both are enabled, the image isn't fixed to the bottom of the page anymore, but `155px` above the bottom *(However, the image is properly being scaled)*.

Of course, I could just change (in `.sticktofooter`) `bottom:0px;` to `bottom: -155px`, and it works on page load, but when I resize my window (and therefore the script resizes my image), the distance between the bottom of the window and the image will increase again *(And decrease when the window is being scaled to its first, original position again)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're using CSS3 transforms to scale the image. The "real" height of the image hasn't changed, so as far as the browser is concerned, it's fixed with `bottom:0px` as requested.

To resolve this, you could shift the transform-origin of the image... but it would be far easier to change the actual width and height via CSS:

```
$('#theimg').css({
    'height': thegoodheight,
    'width': 'auto' /* maintains proportions */
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/AyfN6/

Comment: So it didn't because the origin/anchor from where it resized was in the center, instead of the middle of the bottom of the image?

Comment: That's my guess, yes.